# How do I install mailparser module via npm on Windows 7 x64?

Tags: node.js

Apologies if there is something obvious I'm missing, I've actually never encountered this error before using npm:

```
C:\work\spark3>npm install mailparser
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mailparser
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mailparser
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/encoding
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mimelib
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/iconv
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mimelib
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/encoding
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/iconv
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/iconv-lite/0.2.7
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/addressparser
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/iconv-lite/0.2.7
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/addressparser

> iconv@2.0.4 install C:\work\spark3\node_modules\mailparser\node_modules\iconv
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\work\spark3\node_modules\mailparser\node_modules\iconv>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: spawn ENOENT
gyp ERR! stack     at errnoException (child_process.js:975:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:766:34)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7600
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\work\spark3\node_modules\mailparser\node_modules\iconv
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.9.5
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing iconv@2.0.4
mailparser@0.3.4 node_modules\mailparser
├── mime@1.2.9
├── mimelib@0.2.12 (addressparser@0.1.3)
└── encoding@0.1.6 (iconv-lite@0.2.7)
```

I have tried the following on my Windows machine after scouring the web:

- Reinstalling Node.js
- Reinstalling Python 2.7
- Ensuring the path for Python is set
- Updating npm
- Installing Visual C++ Express 2010
- Installing node-gyp globally

Comment: The problem is actually with the `iconv` module which, [according to its GitHub page](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-iconv), "may or may not work with Windows". Since `mailparser` declares it as an optional dependency, try downloading the mailparser source and remove `iconv` from `package.json` as a dependency.

Comment: Ahh I see, wasn't sure if it was a problem with iconv or node-gyp. I'll give that a shot - thanks robert

Comment: Robert, do you want to add this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is actually with the iconv module which, [according to its GitHub page](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-iconv), "may or may not work with Windows".

Since mailparser declares it as [an optional dependency](https://github.com/andris9/mailparser/blob/master/package.json#L31), try downloading the mailparser source and remove iconv from `package.json` as a dependency.